# How can I generate a GUID for a VS2012/13 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, guid

I've been copying some VS projects so that they each have a 2008 and a 2012 version project file (one with compiler version v90, one with v110). I need to give the copied projects (the 2012 ones -- the new ones) a new GUID. Thus far I've just had another VS2013 window open where I'm making dummy projects, unloading them, and copying their GUID to use in the new projects I'm making.

Is there a GUID generator or some better way than creating a new project in VS, unloading it, and then copying it's GUID and replacing it in the new project (that also has to be unloaded, which takes time when you have to do it a lot)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS comes with a GUID tool which you can find here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe

(Or similar based on your installation path)

Comment: Yes but that seems to be a general GUID generator, while MsVS projects GUIDS have specific formats.

Comment: I don't see how, when I look at a project's Common Properties -> Build Properties, the Project Identifier is just a regular GUID, with the format {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.

Comment: Yes, I might have confused the Project GUID with Project Type GUID.

Comment: Note this tool is also available via the 'Tools -> Create GUID' option in VS2013. It worked like a charm.